# Term to describe a phrase so obvious that subtext is expected?

Tags: connotation, phrasing

I am trying to convey an idea that seems so obvious to people that their mind struggles to find some alternate meaning or subtext to latch on to when they hear it conveyed.

Consider "It is June". This statement has a very obvious and straightforward meaning. So obvious that if you hear it you will likely think "there's no reason to SAY that unless you're trying to convey some additional information; what connotations does 'June' have? Is he a [sport] fan and commenting on the impending start of the season? Is he celebrating the end of spring semester? Is he reminding me that our friend's birthday is this month? There's gotta be something, no one would ever just observe the current month for no reason."

Is there a word or phrase to describe this situation?

Comment: they are being ***subtle***

Comment: @Jim what if they aren't? This question is about how to describe things that always come across as subtle.

Comment: Oh, you asking what is it called when one expects subtlty or something more but none is intended??  Then it’s like, “Duh!!”  I suppose they are just being ***lame***

Comment: Your description brings to mind "hidden in plain sight."  That's not the same, but it gives me a similar feeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could describe it as a violation of one of [Grice's Maxims](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Grice.pdf).
Specifically, the second maxim of quantity.

- Maxims of Quantity

  1. Make your contribution as informative as is required.
  2. Do not make your contribution more informative than is required.

If you make your contribution to the conversation more informative than is required, the Maxim of Relevance is invoked (by the addressee) to try to find out why you did so. This is under the control of the addressee, however, not the speaker, which is why the Maxim of Relevance is the single maxim in the list that is impossible for a speaker to violate.

Relevance, in fact, is the source of a very useful [theory of pragmatic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_theory).

Comment: Gricean implication was brought up as an answer elsewhere as well. This is probably the right direction to study this concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**a subtle suggestion** Here is a definition of *subtle*  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/subtle)

> So slight as to be difficult to detect or describe; elusive: a subtle
>   smile. Difficult to understand; abstruse: an argument whose subtle
>   point was lost on her opponent.  Able to make fine distinctions: a
>   subtle mind.  Operating in a hidden, usually injurious way; insidious:
>   a subtle poison.

In poetry, the symbolist procedure as typified by Paul Verlaine—was to use *subtle suggestion* instead of precise statement. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Verlaine)